# Starting qcachegrind from terminal - is it possible to specify the file for preload?

Tags: qcachegrind

Is it possible to make qcachegrind preload specific file when opening? I.e. if you type `qcachegrind` in the terminal GUI will open and then you will need to select the file manually. I want to do something like `qcachegrind /path/to/profile` so that when GUI opens it already has desired file loaded